# How can I check if a referenced object is missing in the inspector in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script for the final fight in a game, in which there are 10 enemies. After all of them are killed, a chest should appear.
This is the script that is on the chest gameObject:

```
public class FinalFight : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] enemies;
    private int num=0;
    private bool fightStarts=true;
    private bool fightOver=false;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (fightStarts&&!fightOver)
        {
            Fight();
            if (num == enemies.Length)
            {
                this.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                fightOver=true;
            }
            else
                num = 0;
        }
    }

    public void Fight()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<enemies.Length;i++)
            if (enemies[i]==null)
                num++;
    }
}
```

In the inspector, I put the 10 enemies in the array. When killing the enemies I can see that their gameObjects dissappear from the array and are shown as `Missing`, but when all of them are killed, the chest won't show. Is there another way of chacking whether the gameObject are missing?

Comment: `this.gameObject.SetActive(true);` - this implies that the current gameobject is inactive, in which case the `Update` method would never be called. Are you sure this method is ever actually invoked?

Comment: Where is this script attached to? If this script is attached to the chest itself, the problem would be that an inactive gameobject would not have it's updated.

Comment: I am new to this so I didn't realize that `Update` will only be called when the gameObject is active. This is most likely the problem - is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, inactive GameObjects will not have its `Update()` called on any of it's components.
So your chest will never have it's `Update()` ran to check for dead enemies to determine if it should show up.

One way to solve this is to just have a general management script like so:

```
// NOTE: This script should be attached to a GameObject,
// the GameObject should be active 24/7. 
public class ChestUnlocker : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField, Tooltip("Contains all the enemies to unlock the target chest")]
    private GameObject[] enemies;

    [SerializeField, Tooltip("The chest to be unlocked once all enemies are defeeated.")]
    private GameObject chestObject;

    private bool fightOver;
    private void Start() {
        fightOver = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Chest is already unlocked, nothing else to do...
        if (fightOver) {
            return;
        }

        // All enemies have not died yet, do nothing...
        if (!AllEnemiesDead()) {
            return
        }

        chestObject.SetActive(true);
        fightOver = true;

        // Or alternatively, you can just destroy this object,
        // since its already done it's task.
        Destroy(this.gameObject);

        // Or if this gameObject has other scripts as well,
        // you can destroy only this component instead.
        DestroyImmediate(this);
    }

    private bool AllEnemiesDead() {
        for (int i=0;i<enemies.Length;i++)
            if (enemies[i]!=null)
                return false
        return true
    }
}
```

This script will be attached to a Game Object *(usually, the Object does literally nothing in the scene except to run these scripts)*, and its role is to just manage the chest depending on the state of the enemies.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**: This is incorrect and as pointed out by others the issue is likely the question of the object being `active` or not. Moral of the story, don't stack overflow before your morning coffee.

`num` is being reset to 0 every frame when `num` does not equal `enemies.Length`.

```
        if (num == enemies.Length){/*...*/}
        else num = 0;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
        if (num != enemies.Length) num = 0;
        else {/*...*/}
```

Therefore, unless all the enemies are defeated in the same frame, (or if enemies is `enemies.Length` is 0) this will never complete.

Remove the `else` section of your condition in the `Update()` method.

Comment: This is unlikely the issue, OP made it such that `fight()` counts the number of dead enemies, and assigns it to `num`. And if the number of dead enemies is exactly all the enemies, then the fight would end; Notice that `fight()` is invoked every update and it only increments `num`, which means OP decided to reset `num` after counting it again. The cause of OP's issue is likely due to `this.gameObject.SetActive(true);`, which implies the current game-object is inactive *(probably attached to chest)*, hence `update()` is not being invoked in the first place.

Comment: You are correct.

Addendum: Since this is recalculated very frame it could be made into a local variable or returned from fight and used directly in the comparison:

```
int defeatedCount = Fight();
if(defeatedCount == enemies.Length)
```

Otherwise, yes, the `active` status is more likely the issue.

Comment: If* this is recalculated